# How to starts adding data to MySQL table with id of !=0

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a page to add new users to the MySQL with PHP. And the problem with this is, that it sets id of a new user to 0 whenever it runs. So I don't want that.. I want it to start from id of 1 and if it exists in table, try more than that like 2 for example.

I don't think for this example, you won't need to look at my php files but if you do, here you can see the `admin_new.php`:

```
    <?php 
$notice = array();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $groups = $_POST['groups'];
    if($groups == "Main Admin"){
        $level = 1;
    }else if($groups == "Administrator"){
        $level = 2;
    }else if($groups == "Content Creator"){
        $level = 3;
    }else if($groups == "Social Media Manager"){
        $level = 4;
    }else{
        $level = 5;
    }
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $notice['email'] = "The email that you have entered is not a valid one";
    }else{
        $registration = new Register();
        $registration->CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
    }   
}
?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Add New Admin
            <small>You can add new admin here</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">addnewadmin.php</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <?php 
    if(isset($notice['validation_email'])) {
        echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['validation_email'].".
            </div>
        ";
    }
    if(isset($notice['username_exists'])) {
        echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['username_exists'].".
            </div>
        ";
    }
    if(isset($notice['email_exists'])) {
        echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['email_exists'].".
            </div>
        ";
    }
    if(isset($notice['success_message'])) {
        echo "
            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Hey!</strong> ".$notice['success_message'].".
            </div>
        ";
    }
    ?>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Required Information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>User name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Temporary password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter password" name="pass" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Group admin</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="groups">
                                    <option value="Main Admin">Main Admin</option>
                                    <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                                    <option value="Content Creator">Content Creator</option>
                                    <option value="Social Media Manager">Social Media Manager</option>
                                    <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            Visit <a href="https://zite.pouyavagefi.com/documentation/types.php">admin types</a> documentation to know the differences between each admin.
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And here is the class that I have used which is called `Register.class.php`:

```
    <?php 
class Register
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function CheckUname($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&($email))
        {
            $chk1 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM admins WHERE user_name= ?");
            $chk1->bindParam(1,$username);
            $chk1->execute();
            if($chk1->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                $notice['username_exists'] = "Try different username";
                return $notice;
            }else{
                $chk2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT email FROM admins WHERE email_address= ?");
                $chk2->bindParam(1,$email);
                $chk2->execute();
                if($chk2->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    $notice['email_exists'] = "The email address that you have entered is already exists in database";
                    return $notice;
                }else{
                    $this->NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level);
                    $notice['success_message'] = "New admin was successfully added";
                    return $notice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function NewAdmin($username,$email,$password,$groups,$level)
    {
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($groups)&&!empty($level))
        {
            $reg = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (user_name, email_address, password_hash, group_admin, date_joined, admin_level) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
            $reg->bindParam(1,$username);
            $reg->bindParam(2,$email);
            $reg->bindParam(3,$password);
            $reg->bindParam(4,$groups);
            $reg->bindParam(5,$level);
            $reg->execute();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can simply use an auto increment column for `ID` , and don't pass anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this commend on mysql terminal:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
```

the above command will make the `id` an `auto_increment` as well as `primary key`. So for every value you insert, `auto_increment` will generate a new value for column `id`, you don't have to assign some value in it.